# Cisco ASA: How to free memory without reboot?

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

How can I free up some memory in our Cisco ASA 5510 without rebooting it?
We urgently need to free memory otherwise it will crash, but we can't reboot it in the next 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First figure out what is eating up your memory

```
sh mem detail
sh proc detail
```

Something like this could bring the memory down but might not be what you desire.  Also remember logging takes memory I belive.

```
clear conf threat-detection
```

Comment: Thanks! We deactivated some options and seems that the memory is decreasing very slowly (aprox 1% every 3 hours). We are hitting now 95% memory usage.